# how to insert data when one of muliple binding ips is diconnected on mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I have 2 PC set including 2 lan ports for each PC.
I've made setting for using replSet.

PC No.1

mongod --bind_ip 127.0.0.1,192.168.0.231,192.168.0.241 --replSet repl --dbpath C:\mongodb\data --port 27017

PC No.2

mongod --bind_ip 127.0.0.1,192.168.0.232,192.168.0.242 --replSet repl --dbpath C:\mongodb\data --port 27017

config = {_id : "repl", members : [{_id:0, host:"192.168.0.231:27017", priority:1},{_id:1, host:"192.168.0.232:27017", priority:1}]};

rs.initiate(config);

mongosh --host 192.168.0.241 --port 27017

I can read all data with both IPs(192.168.0.231,192.168.0.241). but i can not receive any result with IP 192.168.0.241 when i use command for "insertOne()" with disconnected with IP 192.168.0.231

and i also can not read any data from my APP with mongo drive with same condition.

plese give your any advice.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a few different concepts being conflated here resulting in a bit of confusion and inconsistent behavior. The short answer is that the application should be using a [connection string for the replica set](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/connection-string/#replica-set-option) rather than a standalone server in order to function properly.

The [`bind_ip` setting](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/program/mongod/#std-option-mongod.--bind_ip) describes what network interfaces the `mongod` processes should use to listen for connections. If the members of the replica set are communicating with each other (e.g. `rs.initiate(config);` was successful) and the client application can also connect to all members of the replica set, then
the binding is properly configured and there are no changes or problems there.

What is happening instead is that you are connecting directly to the members of the replica set individually. Assuming the replica set is functioning properly, one of the two members will be in the `PRIMARY` state and the other will be a `SECONDARY`. While both can serve read operations, only the `PRIMARY` can accept writes. This seems to be similar to the behavior that you are describing.

The fact that Mongosh can read data from both members but your application can only read from one probably relates to [read preference](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/read-preference/). By default, drivers will use a read preference of `primary` but Mongosh will probably automatically configure reads from other members when connected directly.

Therefore you should configure your application to use an appropriate connection URI. This should specifically include the replica set options as well as [read preference](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/connection-string/#read-preference-options) if you would like to read from any members. The connection string would probably look something like the following in your situation:

```
mongodb://192.168.0.231:27017,192.168.0.232:27017/?replicaSet=repl&readPreference=primaryPreferred
```

Comment: Thanks a lots. Is there any way to add multiple biding ip to a comfig member?

Comment: Yes, via a [list of comma-separated values](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/program/mongod/#std-option-mongod.--bind_ip). But you're already doing that according to the text in the original question, so I'm not sure why you're asking here?

Comment: I am really in trouble with the replSet option using multiple IPs on another network (A net and B net).

I have 3 PCs and they have 2 LAN ports for each computer and they are separated by A net and B net.

I can use replSet option and make a binding IP (--bind_ip 127.0.0.1,192.168.0.233,192.168.0.234)

But I can not make the member in rs.config for all IPs. It just allows one IP for each PC.

So, I can not connect to MongoDB using the B network if the A network, which is set in the member, is dead.

Is there another solution to my situation?